# Are beginners generally accepted into Open Source projects?

Tags: contributor

Whilst some open source projects would be too specialised and too complex, in general, are beginners welcomed into open source projects? When I say beginner I mean someone who has taken an introductory university course on programming and had a year or two of basic programming experience for scientific purposes (mainly solving problems for assignments). Basically someone who has a strong grasp of most programming concepts but may not have a huge amount of experience in code structuring, unit and integration testing, and larger projects.

Comment: There is no 'general' answer. It is all completely different in different projects and environments.

Comment: Interpret 'general' as 'on the whole' and I think this is answerable

Comment: I think it can be very difficult for a true beginner to get involved in a project. We took on a contributor who is still going to school. I don't think we could have gotten him up to speed without our chat channel to facilitate mentoring him. On the bright side, he's no longer a beginner. (He's actually working on a patch for Roslyn now!) FLOSS can be a great way to ratchet up your skill set if you get involved with the right project/people.

Comment: But when you say true beginner do you mean someone who's just learnt how to program, someone who doesn't know how to program, or someone who knows how to program but has never worked on a large project?

Comment: In the projects I'm involved with we evaluate the contributions, not the contributors.  I was a beginner when I joined the projects 20 years ago, having over 30 years of FORTRAN IV experience but no C experience.  It took some getting used to the lower-case letters and counting from zero, but I survived and have had many contributions accepted.  The only push-back at the beginning was someone not liking the .mil email address that I was using at the time.

Comment: I understand where the put on hold as too broad is coming from, but I would appreciate some suggestions to improve the question if possible. I understand I may need to refine scope but the relative agreement of the answers seems to suggest there is consensus among the community.

Comment: The question seems to focus solely on the coding aspects of "being accepted". IMO that is not enough - you can create patches for a project for years, without interacting with its community much.

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher Are you responding to the OP's "how do I improve this?" comment? The question was closed as too broad, but you seem to be saying it's too narrowly focused ("focused solely on the coding aspects"). Bear of little brain is confused :)

Comment: More like "the OP is asking the wrong question" - one way to make an improvement out of my comment would be to clarify whether you want to be accepted as a (contributing) person, or have your contributions accepted. If that seems to abstract, one could think about it as a questions like "Would they invite me to a meeting or conference they are having, or prefer to just discuss my contributions there among themselves?".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The world of open source is, almost by definition, one in which groups of complete strangers come together to combine their talents and produce a unified result. There may well be some projects where all contributors know each other and have great experience, but in the main you will be judged on the quality of your contributions.

So, I think it is fair to say that beginners who submit quality contributions, who follow the project's guidelines and procedures, and who are respectful to the community of contributors would be welcomed.

After all, a lack of of experience does not necessarily equate with a lack of good or at least fresh ideas. Indeed there a number of people here on this site who, though lacking years of experience, are still active in the FLOSS community.

But the key is to follow the project's norms. If, as you say, you don't have much knowledge of structuring, or unit testing, and the project is heavily into that approach, it behooves you to study the existing code base before making a submission.

Look at the existing unit/integration tests. Learn how they are written for this project. Which test frameworks do they use? How exhaustive are they?

Look at previous pull requests similar to the one you are considering (start small with a bug fix, for example). What did it include? Just the fix? A detailed commit message? Tests to ensure the bug does not reappear (without being noticed)?

Walk in the footsteps of those who've gone before you, and you should be welcomed with open arms.

An if you run into a project where you need 20 years of experience before they'll even acknowledge your existence ... skip it and move to another project.